# Using XDocument.Descendants to get all "signal"s but only want certain "signal"s

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml like this:

```
<signals>
  <signal name="N$41"></signal>
  <signal name="S$80"></signal>
  <signal name="EPD_PWR">
    <contactref element="HS1" pad="40" />
  </signal>
  ...
</signals>
```

And I am getting all the signals by using this code:

```
var result = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(filename).Descendants("signal");

            foreach (var sig in result)
            {
                signals += sig.Attribute("name").Value.ToString() + " ";
            }
MessageBox.Show(signals);
```

The problem is I just wanna store all "signal" that has a contactref of element i.e. "HS1" and dont store them if they have no contactref or a different element name than "HS1".

How would I do this if it is possible?

Comment: Try following :             List<XElement> hs1 = doc.Descendants("signal")
                .Where(x => (x.Element("contactref") != null) && (x.Element("contactref").Attribute("element") != null) && ((string)x.Element("contactref").Attribute("element") == "HS1"))
                .ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use normal LINQ filtering via `Where`:

```cs
var result = XDocument.Load(filename)
    .Descendants("signal")
    .Where(s => s.Element("contactref")?.Attribute("element")?.Value == "HS1");
```

I'd also then suggest using `string.Join` to build up your string:

```cs
string signals = string.Join(" ", result.Select(s => s.Attribute("EPD_PWR").Value)));
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Was easier then I thought!